# making first row of tableView Empty iphone

Tags: iphone

In my app i have a tableView. I want to show tomorrows date (next date) in first row of the table view and other data in rest of the rows. How can i make first row empty and then show date in that.

my code is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}





    NSUInteger row=[indexPath row ];

if (row==0) {
    cell.textLabel.text=@"hi";
}

else{



cell.textLabel.text = [dataFromXml objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


// cell.detailTextLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:row];
```

NSString *detail   = [dataFromXml2 objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *dist=[distance objectAtIndex:row];

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"##0.## km"];
[numberFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"##0.## km"];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[dist doubleValue]];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];




NSString *detailSting=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"" - ""%@",detail,formattedString];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailSting;

[numberFormatter release];

cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
self.rowImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"redicon.png"];

cell.imageView.image= self.rowImage;


return cell;

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a special case in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    /* handle special cell */
}
else {
    /* do your usual stuff */
}
```

To get tomorrow's date you can do:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tomorrow = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
```

Then using NSDateFormatter to convert to a string.

Comment: application crashes with this

Comment: Can you give crash info (is it on NSString *detail = [dataFromXml2 objectAtIndex:row]; NSString *dist=[distance objectAtIndex:row]; ?)

Comment: no it shows main class in crash . and does not show anything 2011-10-14 15:34:02.743 booktable[774:207] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: it shows first row but the thing is it is not shifting data rows 1 row down but not showing first row of data from xml. i want to shift rows down and wants first row to show data

Comment: You need to shift your data accordingly, if (row > 0) then [dataFromXml objectAtIndex:row-1]; NSString *detail = [dataFromXml2 objectAtIndex:row-1]; NSString *dist=[distance objectAtIndex:row-1];

Comment: Yes mate done. Thanks can you answer the other part of question as well? how to show date after today?